# How to keep increasing the value of a BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

I have a series of BigInteger problems that require the use of constantly increasing a BigInteger.  I proposed a loop, but that is extremely tricky due to the fact that BigIntegers and BigDecimals are immutable.

Here is an example of one of the programs I am trying to make.  It is a method trying to find BigIntegers larger than Long.MAX_VALUE that are divisible by 2 or 3.

```
    public void divisibleBy2Or3() {
    BigInteger min = new BigInteger("9223372036854775808");
    int j = 0;
    BigInteger increment = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger divideBy2 = new BigInteger("2");
    BigInteger divideBy3 = new BigInteger("3");
    while (j < 10) {
        BigInteger a = min.add(increment);
        BigInteger b = a.divide(divideBy2); BigInteger c = a.divide(divideBy3);
        if (b.multiply(divideBy2) == a || c.multiply(divideBy3) == a) {
            System.out.print(a + " ");
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is I can't seem to figure out how to get the BigInteger that I am testing for each iteration of the loop to add itself with each iteration.  I'm also a little unsure as to if the multiply methods actually work for this scenario, as whenever I run the program, it hangs and shows a blank console

Comment: Just reassign to the same variable in order to change it. And the reason you aren't getting any output is that your comparison is wrong. Use `.equals` instead of `==`.

Comment: why would you need to search these values? multiples of 2 and 3 have clearly defined properties that allow the generation of such values without searching.

Comment: `BigInteger b =new BigInteger("123"); b =  b.add( BigInteger.ONE );`

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of your current value using a variable declared outside the loop - otherwise it keeps going back to `min + 1`.

```
static final BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.ONE;
static final BigInteger TWO = ONE.add(ONE);
static final BigInteger THREE = TWO.add(ONE);

public void divisibleBy2Or3() {
    BigInteger min = new BigInteger("9223372036854775808");
    int j = 0;
    // Add this.
    BigInteger value = min;
    while (j < 10) {
        value = value.add(ONE);
        BigInteger b = value.divide(TWO);
        BigInteger c = value.divide(THREE);
        if (b.multiply(TWO).equals(value) || c.multiply(THREE).equals(value)) {
            System.out.print(value + " ");
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```